# Magento API - How to create a partial shipment

Tags: magento, soap

I'm using the Magento API (SOAP V2) to create a shipment.

I need to create a partial order but can't seem to get it to work. It just sets all items as shipped.

From the documentation, I'm using:

```
$result = $proxy->salesOrderShipmentCreate($sessionId, '200000006', array('8', '1'), 'shipment comment');
```

where

```
array('8','1')
```

is the order_item_id and quantity.

I've tried manually putting the sku and the actual product id in and it still doesn't register as a partial order.

Can anyone help me creating a partial order?

Answer (score 0):

So I just did a quick browse through docs and I feel like the `array(8,1)` is essentially sample data ( `array('order_item_id' => '8', 'qty' => '1'),` ) I googled `salesOrderShipmentCreate`  and looked at magento's documentation and it seems there are only 2 values in said array ID and qty. try adopting this syntax and see if it works. However I am not terrribly familiar with magento order creation but, it seems like if this problem needs to be handled on a regular basis, customization seems like a probable route.